# В JavaScript, в простом примере нет отрисовки с "canvas"

Tags: javascript, canvas

Уже пробовал писать простейшую игру на JS, там всё работало как часы, сейчас начал писать другую, написал уже основные функции, решил проверить отрисовку фона в canvas и столкнулся с тем, что отрисовки нет. Почистил код от всего, что не связано с фоновой картинкой и canvas - ом, но отрисовки всё равно нет!

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Кости</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    body {
      background: #29272F;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .img {
      position: absolute;
      top: -1000px;
    }
    
    canvas {
      border: 3px solid white;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas width="600" height="600" id="game"></canvas>
  <img class="img" id='bg' src="img/bg.png">

  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var bg = document.getElementById('bg');

    context.drawImage(bg, 0, 0); //Отрисовка фона
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Картинка "bg.png" лежит в указанном каталоге и при наведении курсора на её код в "Brackets" - она отображается.

Comment: ошибки в консоли?

Comment: Я начинающий программист и могу что либо не знать. Какой консоли, та что в браузере? Использую Хром - ошибок нет, валидатором кода проверял тоже - ошибок нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это все потому что вы очень спешите. Дождитесь загрузки изображения.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('game')
const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
const bg = document.getElementById('bg')
bg.onload = () => {
  context.drawImage(bg, 0, 0)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Только я не понимаю почему в другой игре, где у меня были десятки изображений - мне не приходилось прибегать к подобным методам и всё работало сразу и сейчас работает.

Comment: @aproDJ, нужно смотреть конкретный код _другой игры_

Comment: @aproDJ Подождите, сейчас он угадает код "в другой игре".

Comment: Я уже понял почему, в другой игре у меня была циклическая постоянная отрисовка, а в этой игре нет такой необходимости. Попробую отделить код. Спасибо!